# How to add custom field on admin that can add and read an php code inside a wordpress?

Tags: field

How to add custom field on admin that can add and read an php code inside a wordpress?

I am really stuck on this problem. I had a gallery plugin "WP Titans gallery plug-in" that install in a complicated theme "Daisho" with a custom theme setting. Now as this gallery plugin added new pages in what we called "Portfolio" setting, there's a lot of custom fields there, I think it was customized by the owner of the plugin, and when I tried to post in the custom field "Description" a php code from another plugin, it can't read.

I need that this php code can be read by a custom field.